# My android app is crashing, can someone help by deciphering my log cat?

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

```
01-04 13:07:11.693: D/AndroidRuntime(281): Shutting down VM
01-04 13:07:11.733: W/dalvikvm(281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ebonybutler.cexample3/com.ebonybutler.cexample3.Second}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.ebonybutler.cexample3.Second.onCreate(Second.java:38)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  ... 11 more
```

Code in line 38-43:

```
ib5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(Second.this, Eighth.class));
  }
});
```

Comment: I did just add a Second java file that they main java file is linked to.  I'm sure my code in the Second java has something to do with this error Second but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Can you post your code, specifically for the `onCreate` method of the `Second` class?

Comment: I have to think it's self-evident that including your code referenced in the stack trace should be included.

Comment: @user1026229 Thanks, make sure you "edit" your original question rather than actually posting it "below" as answer

Answer (score 2):

Where logcat says

```
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.ebonybutler.cexample3.Second.onCreate(Second.java:38)
```

It's telling you that you're trying to use a null reference on line 38 of Second.java.

What's on line 38?

**EDIT**

If line 38 is `ib5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`, then your variable `ib5` is null. But you'll need to probably post the whole method if that doesn't help.

Comment: This is what's on line 38:ib5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

Comment: ib5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(Second.this, Eighth.class));
    
   }
  });

Comment: Add the code by editing your original question (where it says 'edit' under the question). Post everything that's in that `onCreate()` function.

Comment: But my guess is that you probably did something like `ib5 = findViewById(R.id.something);` and `findViewById()` is returning null because it can't find that view or the ID is wrong or whatever. Then you're trying to use that null variable to set a listener on a view that it can't find. Hence the crash. Maybe double check the IDs.

Comment: I updated the question with the code, but you should still post the full code of your `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a NullPointerException at Line 38 in Second.java class

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 13:07:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.ebonybutler.cexample3.Second.onCreate(Second.java:38)

Answer (score 0):

You have a NullPointerException - probably in Second.java, line 38.

Answer (score 0):

My first days with Android resulted in a few `NullPointerException`s in my `onCreate()` methods because I tried to access some elements of the `Activity` that hadn't gotten fully initialized at that point.  You may want to try pushing some of that stuff into `onStart()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch i have are you calling findViewById **before** calling *setContentView()* .Just saying i started my Android journey with a few of those :)